# Copying row from a sheet to another on clicking a button getting an error

Tags: vba, excel

After Clicking on a button some rows are copying from a sheet to another but I am getting an error:

> This workbook contains links to one or more external sources that could be unsafe.
>   If you trust the links,update them to get the latest data. Otherwise, you can keep working with the data you have.
>   [Update]    [Don't Update]   [Help]

I have tried clicking <kbd>Update</kbd> & <kbd>Don't Update</kbd> but it is not copying the data in either manner.

I am putting the value from a cell to wbLocationPath :

```
Set wbLocationPath = WSheet.Range("A2") 

While wbLocationPath.Value <> ""
    If IsWorkBookOpen(wbLocationPath.Value) Then
        For Each wks In Workbooks
            If (wks.Path & "\" & wks.Name) = wbLocationPath Then
                Set wb = wks
                Exit For
            End If
        Next wks
    Else
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(wbLocationPath.Value, ReadOnly:=False)
    End If
```

so during debugging I got the error on setting the wb value.

`wbLocationPath.value` is having the path what is in A2 as `c\users\me\desktop\project\XYZ.xlsx`.

IsWorkBookOpen(wbLocationPath.Value) is returning false so control comes on else part which gives error.

I don't have any problem in pasting the value . My code is working fine for other thousands of filepath but it's not working just for some filepath .
I have some folders, I copied the every file's data from every folder. Getting the problem in a specific folder's("FOOD ADD") some specific files.
As I have some file name like "10024125 (01-0RD)" so all these type of file's datails copying but where the filename is "10016818 (03-1RD) FOOD ADD" is not copying & through the error what I have mentioned.

Comment: it is working as it was pasted many rows ,but only getting for some filepath.
I have added d code.

Comment: Can you go into Excel Options, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings and add the filepath to the Trusted Locations?

Comment: I have added the path of my folder in Trusted Locations but still it shows the  popup with same error.

Comment: If `wbLocationPath` is a string type variable, you would not be using `wbLocationPath.Value`. You would only use `.Value` if `wbLocationPath` as a Range type variable.

Comment: yes!! I have defined Dim wbLocationPath As Range .

Comment: Perhaps this is just a typo but `c/users/me/desktop/project/XYZ.xlsx.` should be `c:\users\me\desktop\project\XYZ.xlsx.`

Comment: Oh!! yes it was typing mistake ... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no problem in VBA code. The problem is in the excel file . The excel was "linked WorkSheet"  i.e  it was linked to any server to update the value in excel whenever you want to open. So You can change the  Link properties from "Data" menu by selecting "EditLink".

there we can change the prompt properties on the basis of your requirement.

please see the following solution from MS support to suppress the message:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826921

Answer (score 0):

If you have the workbook open and it comes from a trusted location (see Excel Options ► Trust Center ► Trust Center Settings ► Trusted Locations), then you should not have a problem using a Paste Special, Values since you are only concerned with the values, not the original formulas. However, a direct value transfer may be sufficient to bypass the warnings. There are also some implicit cell parent worksheet references that should be made explicit.

```
with tmpSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1))  '<~~ note all parts belong to tmpSheet
end with

with pasteSheet
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c = "ABC" Then
            'the following is an alternative method of direct value transfer
            .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, columns.count) = _
                 c.Resize(1, columns.count).Value
        End If
    Next c
end with
```

Note that when you were defining *rng*. the parent worksheet was explicit for the `.Range` but not the `.Cells` that made up the range. Also, the direct value transfer is a more efficient method of getting the values across without the clipboard.

Comment: during debug the error is coming after this line...: 
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(wbLocationPath.Value, ReadOnly:=False)

wbLocationPath is having the filepath from where I have to copy the row.

Comment: That might have been something to include in your question. Edit the original question and put it in as an addendum explaining exactly what error you are receiving and how you got the value in `wbLocationPath.Value`. Usually that is just `wbLocationPath`.

Comment: I have updated the question. Yes I was not getting that from where the error is coming, so now  i got that the error is coming in setting the wb.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the IsWorkBookOpen is not expecting the full path and workbook name that you are sending it. If it was only expecting the [Workbook.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195422.aspx) then you are never going to get a match when you send it the [Workbook.FullName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834975.aspx).

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen2(sWS As String)
    Dim b As Long
    For b = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        'Debug.Print Workbooks(b).FullName
        If lcase(Workbooks(b).FullName) = lcase(sWS) Then _
            Exit For
    Next b
    IsWorkBookOpen2 = CBool(b <= Workbooks.Count)
End Function
```

This replacement routine performs a non-case-sensitive comparison on the full path and filename (aka [Workbook.FullName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834975.aspx)) of the open workbooks to the value which you have stored in `WSheet.Range("A2")`.

Note that it is called `IsWorkBookOpen2` and not `IsWorkBookOpen`.